# jquery not working in .appended content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div, which has content populated on load (a bunch of 'span' tags with a delete link in each. clicking the delete button will remove that span. Now you can also add new 'span' tags to it using a separate button (each with their own delete button). The initially loaded span delete buttons work fine, but the newly added ones do not delete.

```
<div class="instances"> 
<span class="item">Instance 1 <a href="#" class="del">delete</a></span>
<span class="item">Instance 2 <a href="#" class="del">delete</a></span>
</div>
<span class="addinstance">Add an instance</span>


$('.addinstance').click(function () {
$('.instances').append('<span class="item">More <a href="#" class="del">delete</a></span> ');
});

$('.instances .del').click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
$(this).parent('.item').hide();
});
```

Check out the fiddle I made for a working version of this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ac7x6/3/

In the fiddle:

1. Click the delete button on Instance 1 - works fine.
2. Click the 'Add an Instance' button - this adds an new entry.
3. Click the 'delete' button on the newly added instance - does not delete.

I have read a lot about this issue, including jquery .on(). Just not sure exactly how to implement them.

Help! :)

Comment: `hide()` just hides the element, does not remove it.

Comment: hide() was just used for simplicity in the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use event delegation for dynamically generated items, If you wanna remove the item then use [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$('.instances').on('click','.del',function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.item').remove();
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac7x6/4/)

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure I tried exactly this and it didn't work... (well obviously I didn't or it would have worked haha!) Thanks for the help and thank you for using my actual example code in your response - that always helps make it a lot more clear.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(document).on("click", '.instances .del', function (event) {
    //your code
});
```